# Exponential inequality: $4^x-9\cdot2^x+8>0$

Tags: exponential-function

I am facing difficulties in solving the following equation:

$$4^x-9\cdot2^x+8>0.$$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

**HINT** Let $y=2^x$ and it becomes the quadratic inequality of $y$, because $4^x=(2^x)^2=y^2$.

Comment: With the limitation that $y>0$ when we consider the possible solutions.

Comment: Could someone explain why there is a downvote here? I've already changed my attitude toward the questions with no attempts. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2992308/394456).

Comment: I don't know, I've only given a suggestion to improve the hint but originally I've upvoted that.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$4^x = (2^x)^2$$

Thus your inequality  is $$ (2^x-1)(2^x-8)>0$$

The solution is $ 2^x<1 $ or $2^x>8$

That is $x<0$ or $x>3$ which could be expressed as $ (-\infty, 0)\cup (3,\infty)$